# Avoid numerical overflow problem in likelihood due to $\exp$

Tags: r, likelihood, numerics

There is a trick called [exp-normalization](https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2014/02/11/exp-normalize-trick/) which is used for dealing with overflow for ratios of the type $$\frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_j \exp(x_j)} = \frac{\exp(x_i-b)}{\sum_j \exp(x_j-b)}$$ by using the result after the equation with $b=\max_i x_i$.

I am looking into the likelihood of a Weibull accelerated failure time model. The log-likelihood involves the contribution

$$\sum_i [V_i - \exp(V_i)]-n\log(\sigma)$$

where

$$V_i = (\log(y_i) - x_i^T\beta)/\sigma$$

With $y$ being a time variable and $X$ covariate matrix the AFT model is given by $y=X\beta+\sigma \epsilon$.

For large data sets and/or $\beta$ sampling from this likelihood (times a prior), using e.g. metropolis algorithm, may encounter numerical overflow when $\exp(V_i)$ becomes infinite for at least one $i$. This happens very rarely but it does happen. Is there a way to prevent this from happening in `R`?

Comment: I think this just means that the target density at the new proposed parameter value is numerically equal to zero (so the proposed parameter value is not at all supported by the data).  So the correct thing to do would be to just set the acceptance probability to zero in such cases and reject such parameter values.

Comment: Provided that there is a constant in the covariates, dividing the observations $y_i$ by their max could improve. The parameter must be backtransformed in the inference results.

Comment: I would characterize this as *underflow* because the contribution to the log likelihood is essentially *negative* infinity.  Provided at least one parameter value has been found that causes no underflow, you can dismiss such circumstances as lying far from the optimum and use various methods to steer your solver away from them.